# Regular expression returning some awkward value

Tags: javascript, html-parsing, html

I have the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //javascript starts

 var patt=/[<](\S+).*>(.*)<\/\1>/;
 var str='<a id="test">hi</a> <p></p>';

 alert(str.match(patt));
 alert(patt.exec(str));

</script>
```

It is expected **to find all tags in a html document**. So ideally it should return `<a id="test">hi</a>, <p></p>`.

But it currently returns `<a id="test">hi</a>, a ,hi`.

***Why is this happening?***

Also another question, **What is the difference between `str.match(patt)` and `patt.exec(str)` and which is better to use?**

Comment: why don't u  use a dom parser instead of regex?

Comment: well, jquery is a veery good dom parser besides other things

Comment: here's a more detailed answer on why not to use regex to parse html : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags . Besides, with jQuery, all you have to do to select all the `a` elements in the document is  : `$('a');`

Comment: But what I need here is an html parser not a dom parser. I am reading html input from a file

Comment: dom stands for "document object model", which is the browser's internal representation of the xml/html string code. jQuery handles that too : `$('your valid html string here...').find('a');`

Comment: Using jQuery, your query would simply be `$(htmlString).find("*");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var patt=/[<](\S+).*>(.*)<\/\1>/g;
```

try to specify the `global` modifier (or it will stop at the first occurrence found).

About your second question MDN is a good resource:
From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

> If the regular expression does not include the `g` flag, returns the same result as regexp.exec(string). If the regular expression includes the `g` flag, the method returns an Array containing all matches. If there were no matches, the method returns null.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the global modifier, `g`, to your regex: `/[<](\S+).*>(.*)<\/\1>/g`.

- If you don't use the `g` global modifier, [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) will return an array containing *the whole first match in the string* as the first element, followed by any *parenthesised match patterns* within the match as subsequent array elements.
- If you do use the `g` modifier, `match` and `exec` will get all the matches from the string.  `match` returns them as an array, and `exec` will return one array for each match (*with* match patterns, as it does without `g`) but multiple calls to `exec` will each return a different match untill all matches have been reported (see below for an exmple).

In general, I would recommend `match` over `exec`, because `exec` relies on the regular expression maintaining state (specifically, `lastIndex`, the index of the string where the match should resume).  I find this to be detrimental if you want to use a regular expression on multiple strings:

```
var reg = /\w/g;
reg.exec("foo"); // ["f"]
reg.exec("foo"); // ["o"]
reg.exec("bar"); // ["r"] -- does not start at the beginning of the string
```

Compare that to the `match` behavior:

```
var reg = /\w/g;
"foo".match(reg); // ["f", "o", "o"]
"bar".match(reg); // ["b", "a", "r"]
// we can now use the arrays to get individual matches
```

However, if you need the get *parenthesised match patterns* for *each match* in a global search, you must use `exec`, since global application of `match` only gets a list of whole matches, not match patterns with those matches.

```
// the ending digit is a match pattern
var reg = /\w(\d)/g;

// match only gets list of whole matches
"d1b4h7".match(reg); // ["d1","b4","h7"] 

// exec gets the match and the match pattern
reg.exec("d1b5h7"); // ["d1","1"]
reg.exec("d1b5h7"); // ["b4","4"]
reg.exec("d1b5h7"); // ["h7","7"]
```

**In conclusion**, it sounds like you want to use `match` with a global modifier, since you don't need match pattern information.  If you do actually need match pattern information, get all matches by using a loop to repeatedly call `exec`, until `exec` returns `null` instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var patt=/<\S+[^>]*>[^<]*<\/\S+>/g;
```

The extra `a` and `hi` are there because you had them as capture groups. This one will only return tags. The one flaw it has is it will match `<begin>dfgdf</diffEnd>`.

Comment: Also: http://www.perlfect.com/articles/regextutor.shtml is a great resource for writing regex pieces.